# Password Reset through Email in android with php mysql database via json

Tags: android, database-performance

I'm new in android and this is my first app and I'm developing an app now with a forgot password in it. In able to access the full feature of the system, the user must login first. When the user click the Forgot Password, it goes to the Forgot Password Activity. In that activity, there's an EditText for email address and a Send button. What I'd like to happen is that, when the user fill-out the email address EditText and click the Send Button, the password will automatically be sent to the email inputted by the user. How can I code it in Android?
i am using mysql database.please help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're asking people to code your first app for you, how will you code your second app?  Get as far as you can by yourself, then narrow down your question to just a small piece that has you stuck.

Comment: You can't code it in Android. You need to write some php code here. Call php service and send password to user. And @mbeckish, +1.

Comment: @mbeckish do you know where can I get such tutorial ? I've been searched for an hour only found [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html/2) :(

Comment: @John - You might not find a tutorial that solves your exact need,  Instead, just go through general Android tutorials until you are comfortable with the Android platform, and are able to come up with your own solutions for simple things like password reset.  You'll get much better results on this site if you are able to code 90% of the app, and just need help on a small piece.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are not given code . I can give you idea. When the user clicks on Forget Password link then it will go Forget Password Activity , in this Activity asked user to put a unique filed which already in your Server database,suppose, email id or phone number or any security question. After give this answer or email then you click submit button . When you will press the submit button then in background match this field with server data field and from server side send password to the given email id and send response after that to Android end. Which will show that you password has been send to your email id successfully .

Thanks.